# Dealing with ambiguous column names in data.table

Tags: r, data.table, heading

I'm reading data from an Excel file into a data.table in R. The file is formatted like so:

```
   COL_1_STUFF COL_2_STUFF COL_3_STUFF
ID EST MOE PCT EST MOE PCT EST MOE PCT
```

That is, for each variable (the `COL`s), there is an estimate, a margin of error, and a percentage given.

The trouble is being created by `read.xlsx2`, which I'm using to import the file like so:

```
data <- as.data.table(read.xlsx2(
  "file.xlsx", sheetIndex = 1L, colIndex = c(1L, 4L, 7L), startRow = 2L))
```

The problem is that `read.xlsx2` assigns the same column name to a bunch of stuff--the import looks something like:

```
ID EST EST EST
```

even if I set `header = FALSE`, I'm apt to get something like

```
X1 X2 X2 X2
```

To circumvent this, I've done the following subsequent to import:

```
data[ , c("col1_est", "EST") := .(EST, NULL)]
data[ , c("col2_est", "EST") := .(EST, NULL)]
data[ , c("col3_est", "EST") := .(EST, NULL)]
```

This strikes me as an odd way to deal with the problem; can anyone suggest an alternate approach to this?

Comment: May be you could try to convert your Excel file to csv and use `fread` of data.table to read the data into R.

Comment: It sounds like you're dealing with multi-row headings. What do you want the output to be like?

Comment: @KFB that crossed my mind, but I'd like to find a solution that doesn't involve that--it's not the case for me, but I could imagine someone having a large number of files formatted like mine looking for a programmatic solution

Comment: @AnandaMahto yes, that's the vocab word I was looking for! as long as I can successfully import to a data frame / data table object without ambiguously named columns, I can deal with the rest of cleaning/manipulation within R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with the `check.names` argument to `fread`, `data.table`, and `setDT`:

```
DT <- read.xlsx2(
  "file.xlsx", sheetIndex = 1L, colIndex = c(1L, 4L, 7L), startRow = 2L)
)
setDT(DT, check.names = TRUE)
```

Automatically adds `.1`, `.2`, etc. to duplicated column names.